# Grep for specfic number format

Tags: grep, regex

I have a Unix script, which within has release numbers which are like this (2.19.0.32) Look like IP's but are not as some are like this `2.23.0.06.DBP`.

I've tried variations of this but comes back empty.

```
egrep "^[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[DBP]$" TEST.LOG
```

Comment: the reason for why your regex returns nothing means there isn't a line like `9.9.9.9.D` in your file.

Comment: @Christian a good regex question will provide enough sample input values to express all of the variability of the actual project data.  Unless I misunderstand, your data format is one or two digits, a dot, one or two digits, a dot, one or two digits, a dot, one or two digits, a dot, then either `DBP` or nothing more.  It is never two late to post a clear, complete question because researchers will continue to view this page for years and years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this simple command:

```
grep -E '^[0-9.]+\.DBP' TEST.LOG
```

If you want your just change your command to this:

```
grep -E '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.DBP' TEST.LOG
```

`+` means: Matches the one or more occurrences of numbers.

Comment: why the `|` in your `[ ]`?

Comment: I pushed a few changes: Zero or more is not a good thing here because we need to match *something* first. The `|` in the `[]` meant a literal pipe char (not required). The `.`s in the longer version need escaping because they mean "any character" outside of a character match (`[]`).